# Is there a configuration of Latex files which can change my key-bindings?

Tags: key-bindings, latex

I am observing what I believe is an odd behavior in Emacs.

I have a Latex file which, when opened, changes the keybindings in my Emacs.

For example, `C-x s` does not save the file anymore, and Emacs does not find the default pdf viewer upon compiling and visualizing the file.

In the modeline I read:

```
-UU0:----F1  letter.tex  Top L1  (LaTex Ref)
```

While normally when I open the other LaTex files I read:

```
-UUU(DOS):----F1  filename.tex  Top L1  (LaTex/P Ref)
```

What should I look at?

The file looks like the following:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsopn,amstext,amscd,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm}

\newcommand{\C3}{\noindent \textcolor{red}{COMMENT.}\vspace{0.5cm}}

\newcommand{\C2}[1]{
\noindent\hspace{0.2\linewidth}\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
\emph{#1}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{0.5cm}
}

\newcommand{\C1}[1]{
\noindent #1
\vspace{0.5cm}
}


\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm no expert in LaTeX modes, but to me looks like you're in aucTeX mode in one case and Latex/P mode in the other. Why it loads one or another might be in the first file line or in your config files

Comment: No: LaTeX/P is just auctex with TeX-pdf-mode switched on.

Comment: Are there any file-local variables declared at the bottom of the strange file?

Comment: @FranBurstall I update the question with the preamble of the file. There is no local variable at the end of the file.

Comment: @k88074: sorry, I can't help.  Your sample file behaves perfectly normally for me.  Does it exhibit the strange behaviour for you?  If not, try bisecting the content of the document to discover when the strange behaviour kicks in.

Comment: "For example, C-x s does not save the file anymore" -- so what *does* it do?  What does `C-h k C-x s` tell you?